# Process zip file into Solr

Tags: solr, apache-tika

I have to process zip file which content multiple zip files and these zip files have xml and image files. I have to index the data into solr, which should gives result as content of XML data.

I tried default solr-Tika example, which returns only zip file names when I queried on it.
How I will achieve this? is Tika is only the way to handle my requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you index the files inside the zip file? Why pass in the zip file?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make Tika work as you want, you probably need to apply [the patch attached to this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2416) to your current Solr.

And yes, if you want to index contents of zip files without any other work on your side, Tika is your only option.